# Optional features does not load

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, control-panel

If I click these items:

1. Start
2. Settings
3. Apps
4. Optional features

A Windows comes up that says "Optional features", but after about two seconds,
the Window closes. I am trying to install some software, and it said I needed to
enable this certain Windows feature for it to work, but I cant seem to get to
the Optional Features to make any changes. I also tried from Admin PowerShell,
and get error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The service cannot be started, either because
it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
```

Comment: Did you perhaps disable any Windows Services? Maybe Windows Update?

Comment: What edition of Windows are you using?  What version of Windows are you using?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @StevenPenny - Reverse those changes and edit your question with any changes to your problem

Comment: @DanielB thanks - I think that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment, it seems the issue was that this service was disabled:

```
Windows Modules Installer
```

Enabling it seems to have fixed the issue. Note I used a tool [1] to do this,
but I think you can also just use the normal Services App.

1. https://github.com/WereDev/Wu10Man